# modify the original list till a string is found

Tags: python, regex, list

I am working on below output that i received from earlier config

```
['Te1/1/1', 'server', 'Ten', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Te1/1/2', 'desc', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Gi1/2/1', 'desc', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']  
['Gi2/1/2', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']  
['Te2/2/1', 'server', 'notconnect', '301', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Po120', 'notconnect', 'unassigned', 'auto', 'auto']  
['Po121', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto']
```

What I want is to remove any string from the list till string "connected" or "disabled" or "notconnect" is found except 1st item.

I had tried below configuration:

```
regex_chk = re.compile("((?:not)*?connect(?:ed)*|disabled|)")

for item in items:
    for i in item[1:]:
        if i != regex_chk:
            item.remove(i)
    print(item)
```

result comes as:

```
['Te1/1/1']
['Te1/1/2']
['Gi1/2/1']
['Gi2/1/2']
['Te2/2/1']
['Po120']
['Po121']
```

Whereas I want the result to be

```
['Te1/1/1', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Te1/1/2', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Gi1/2/1', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']  
['Gi2/1/2', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']  
['Te2/2/1', 'notconnect', '301', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
['Po120', 'notconnect', 'unassigned', 'auto', 'auto']  
['Po121', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto']
```

Comment: Check how you're testing against the regex. `i != regex_chk` doesn't do it.

Comment: just add a break in your loop when it's matched.

Answer (score 1):

First, You should change the regular expression pattern.
Second, just break when you got a match.

```
for i in item[1:]:
    if re.match("((?:not)*?connect(?:ed)*|disabled)", i):
        break
    else:
        item.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple pattern works for me.
Try it

```
  for item in items:
     for i in item[1:]:
         if re.match('connected|notconnect|disabled', i):
             break
         item.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `((?:not)*?connect(?:ed)*|disabled|)` also matches strings like `notconnected` or `notnotconnecteded` and the `|` at the end makes it also match any other position.

You are also not using the regex in `if i != regex_chk:` It could be like `if not regex_chk.match(i)` instead.

But you don't need a regex for your data, you can use startswith as the words are all at the start of the string.

```
items = [
    ['Te1/1/1', 'server', 'Ten', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR'],
    ['Te1/1/2', 'desc', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR'],
    ['Gi1/2/1', 'desc', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver'],
    ['Gi2/1/2', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver'],
    ['Te2/2/1', 'server', 'notconnect', '301', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR'],
    ['Po120', 'notconnect', 'unassigned', 'auto', 'auto'],
    ['Po121', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto']
]

for item in items:
    for i in item[1:]:
        if not i.startswith(("notconnect", "connected", "disabled")):
            item.remove(i)
            continue
        break
    print(item)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/t1ZMA2)

Output

```
['Te1/1/1', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']
['Te1/1/2', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']
['Gi1/2/1', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']
['Gi2/1/2', 'disabled', 'routed', 'full', '1000', 'No', 'Transceiver']
['Te2/2/1', 'notconnect', '301', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']
['Po120', 'notconnect', 'unassigned', 'auto', 'auto']
['Po121', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a short

```py
import re
l = ['Te1/1/1', 'server', 'Ten', 'connected', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']  
regex_chk = re.compile("(?:not)?connect(?:ed)?|disabled")
print(list(filter(lambda x: not regex_chk.fullmatch(x), l)))
# ['Te1/1/1', 'server', 'Ten', 'trunk', 'full', '10G', '10Gbase-LR']
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##jY@9CsJAEIT7PMWiRe7AX@wESWljJXYicrlbzeHmLmxWieC7xxyIrbLFN1PsMNM8pYph1fe@biILMGYEGzjmB1zOh8snkLfID@SkDhgSbAwBraBLRvgebklc7kSJy8X2g9K0ON3t8xNAxnjF7myr25DOOLOxbjyhGqliHaLo4pM5WHS6eDnfmpLQjXTWsA@iyLeiLp4EWZGpS2egW8PwCt/kWWpQG7GV6vQESGudjX9M@ad9378B).

`filter(lambda x: not regex_chk.fullmatch(x), l)` fetches all list items not fully matching the regex of yours.